# TabControl inside a TabControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol

I am trying to create horizontal tabs that load vertical tabs dynamically using WPF something like below. I want to create something similar, this is not a screenshot of my application.

[image: Target screenshot]

It seems like I cannot create a tab control inside a tab item.

My XAML file has the following code where I am trying to add a `TabControl` inside the content of the tab:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
   <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
         <!-- this is the header template-->
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
         <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
         <DataTemplate>
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding steps}">
               <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <!-- this is the header template-->
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
               <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                  <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
   </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

My C# code includes the following objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }

public AddElement()
{
   Steps step = new Steps();
   step.display = "1";

   Steps step2 = new Steps();
   step.display = "2";

   ObservableCollection<Steps> stepsList = new ObservableCollection<Steps>();
   stepsList.Add(step);
   stepsList.Add(step2);

   Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
   Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = "One's content", Steps = stepsList });
   Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = "Two's content" });

}

public sealed class TabItem
{
   public string Header { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<Steps> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Steps
{
   public string display { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue ? that tab is created as shown in picture ..isn't it ?

Comment: This is just a picture I am trying to create something similar

Comment: You seem to have a typo here. Your inner TabControl.ItemsSource binds to steps instead of Steps. Must be capital S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code, that you need to fix to make it work as intended.

- There is a typo in the binding of the `Steps` property. It has to start with a capital letter.

  ```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}">
  ```
- Remove the last from the XAML or put it in a `Grid` like below. As it is, the code will not compile, as you can only set a single element as content in a `DataTemplate`.

  ```
  <DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding steps}">
           <!-- ...other code. -->
        </TabControl>          
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Content}" />
     </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- You bind to `Header` and `Content` properties on `Steps` items in XAML. This type does not have any of these properties, only `display`. You could introduce these properties and remove `display`.

  ```
  public class Steps
  {
     public string Header { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- In `AddElement` you only modify the `step` instance, not `step2`, so it will be empty. Initialize both, e.g. with the abovementioned additional properties.

  ```
  Steps step = new Steps();
  step.Header = "Header 1";
  step.Content = "Content 1";

  Steps step2 = new Steps();
  step2.Header = "Header 2";
  step2.Content = "Content 2";
  ```
- If you want the tab strip of your inner `TabControl` to be displayed vertically on the left, you have to set the [`TabStripPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Controls_TabControl_TabStripPlacement) property accordingly.

  ```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" TabStripPlacement="Left">
  ```

The result will look like this with default WPF styles.

[image: Screenshot of the application]